# Arduino Leonardo doesn't get auto-detected in Windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: arduino, driver, windows

I recently purchased an Arduino Leonardo to control my Sumo robot. I plugged it in to my friends computer and was able to use the Arduino IDE to upload code to the board and run a simple wheel-test program. When I got home and sat down to play around with it myself, I discovered that it wouldn't connect to my computer.

I plugged the micro-usb in to my computer and the board turns on and the LED goes into it's two-second pulse, but Windows 7 64bit never auto-detects new hardware. I've searched around on Google and tried some of the things that were suggested and it still doesn't work.

I manually installed the Leonardo driver in the System section of the Widows Control Panel and it still doesn't register the device. I've tried manually changing the port of the device from COM1 all the way up through COM9, hoping that my computer was just stupid and didn't recognize what it was doing.

I'm using a Gateway laptop (I looked around for a model name or number, but it doesn't seem to have one. It's just a cheap development machine that I bought at Wal-Mart)

Any suggestions?

**Solution:** The crappy USB cable I was using did not have a data connection, so even though it would power the board, Windows was never able to establish a connection to the device. Terrible cable. :(

Comment: Similar question [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29626/arduino-usb-not-detected-in-device-manager)

Comment: Is it plugged into a USB-3.0 port? The leonardo drivers have issues with some USB-3.0 controllers.

Comment: Apparently the USB cable I was using didn't have a working data connection and was intended for charging only. Meh. Changing to a different cable made everything work perfectly. Of course, it pisses me off that cables can be sold that function differently than all other cables, but that's a rant for another day.

Comment: @EricRyanHarrison the cheap charging cables piss **everyone** off. Glad it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, step by step. Does windows make a sound as if it has found new hardware? Does anything pop up or Device Manager show a new device (COM1 is default for windows, not related to Arduino necessarily)?

If not, then the Leonardo board isn't doing anything to be enumerated. This is likely a hardware issue. Try a different USB cable or test it to make sure it works well. Perhaps a jumper is missing or a solder bridge is missing (on Arduino uno there are two points in the back that need soldering).

Did you follow the instructions Here in the [communications](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardLeonardo) section?

Comment: No sound. What it eventually ended up being was that the USB cable I was using was from a simple speaker and only had power and ground and didn't have data. I plugged the arduino into a cable from my cell phone and everything worked exactly as expected.

Comment: If you add "try changing the cable" to your answer, ill mark yours as correct. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: @EricRyanHarrison: I'm happy to hear it's resolved. I added info about the cable in the question while still leaving it generic.

Comment: This has given me an idea for a small electronics project. I'm going to build a USB cable tester. Something that I can plug in to a cable and make sure that both data AND power are available.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the problem was the USB3 port, plugging it into the USB2 port the driver was installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Windows 7 USB driver fails to install, fixed. First Try FAIL and FIX

http://youtu.be/aAPCP5I1OjY

With a Thank you to Connor Wolf for this information about the USB-3.0 port. The Leonardo drivers have issues with some USB-3.0 controllers.

Connor Wolf also on YouTube, (Electronics)

I also had to download and run "**CDM v2.08.30 WHQL Certified.exe**" see download link inthe descritiption in the video, (not allowed to post that download here)

Comment: It's very unclear what you're saying here.

Comment: I upvoted you because the information that "The Leonardo drivers have issues with some USB-3.0 controllers" gave me the clue I needed - I moved the USB plug to a 2.0 port and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[I had this problem today](http://letsmakerobots.com/robot/project/mounting-testing-and-tunning-insect-bot-mini-iii). It was the USB cable that was for power only. I used a USB with data connections and everything was fine!

Comment: Freaking annoying, right? I still think they shouldn't be allowed to even make power-only USB cables.